# How to list characters of a particular frequency in a string

Tags: c#

The scenario is for example a string "THIS IS A TEST " now for eg path length is set = 2 (it may be different its up to us) the result should be "I" because this is the only string repeating twice.If path length is set = 3 so the result should be (T,S,SPACES) kindly help me in this.

Comment: Can you provide a couple more examples of your input and expected output, your actual output, and code you've tried so far? It's not clear right now as it is.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you wanna get most repeated character in your string or something?

Comment: I think he wants a list of characters which repeat a given number of times.

Comment: it looks like he wants to give up a number and want to get each character (including spaces) that occur the amount of times equal to the number they used as input

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. One solution involves an `IDictionary<char, int>`. I'm sure someone will write it up.

Comment: @jdphenix "this is a test" i need only those char occurring twice in a string if i set the repeat length = 2  means the output should be only those char repeating twice in a string , in case of any different length the output is dependent on length if a want char repeating 3 times so the result should be those char (including spaces) repeating thrice in a string

Comment: @MirzaDanishBaig thanks its helpful but can you make it more simple ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lengthy solution i have coded :) without group by.

```
public static void GetNumberOfTimesACharacterOccuredInAString(string text, int number)
{
        Dictionary<char, int> CharactorNumberOfOccurence = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        int count = 1;

        foreach (char c in text.ToLower())
        {
            if (CharactorNumberOfOccurence.Any(a => a.Key.Equals(c)))
            {
                count = CharactorNumberOfOccurence.Where(a => a.Key.Equals(c)).Select(a => a.Value).FirstOrDefault() + 1;
                CharactorNumberOfOccurence.Remove(c);
                CharactorNumberOfOccurence.Add(c, count);
            }
            else
            {
                CharactorNumberOfOccurence.Add(c, count);
            }
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> charactor in CharactorNumberOfOccurence)
        {
            if (charactor.Value.Equals(number))
            {
                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(charactor.Key))
                    Console.WriteLine("SPACE");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(charactor.Key.ToString().ToUpper());
            }
        }
}
```

With group by it is very simple :)

```
public static void GetNumberOfTimesACharacterOccuredInAString(string text, int number)
{
            List<char> result = text.GroupBy(x => x).Where(y => y.Count() == number).Select(y => y.Key).ToList();

            foreach (char c in result)
            {
                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SPACE");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
                }
            }
 }
```

Comment: This is full running code, you just need to invoke the method by calling like this `GetNumberOfTimesACharacterOccuredInAString("THIS IS A TEST", 3)`

Answer (score 13):

```
string item = "THIS IS A TEST ";
List<char> result = item.GroupBy(x => x).Where(y => y.Count() == 2).Select(y => y.Key).ToList();
```

this returns a List of characters, appearing two times (`I`)

I group all characters in the given string and compare the count of their appearence with `2`

Comment: I suppose if you make the `2` a variable they could input as to change the number of occurences it checks for, it would be what OP needs.

Comment: @maam27 - yes that would be an option

Comment: to me it looks like this would be what OP requested help with ,since it can be with a variable. so you have my upvote

Answer (score 2):

```
string content = "THIS IS A TEST ";

content.GroupBy(c => c).Where(c => c.Count() == 3).Select(c => c.Key);
```

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way to do this is to create a lookup from number of repetitions to the list of characters repeating that many times:

```
var content = "this is a test";
var lookup = content
    .GroupBy(ch => ch)
    .ToLookup(grp => grp.Count, grp => grp.Key);

var twiceRepeatingChars = lookup[2];
var thriceRepeatingChars = lookup[3];
// and so on
```

Comment: Isn't this actually less efficient if you're changing the string every time rather than the frequency, or if you're only applying the function once to a string?

Comment: You're right, it's more efficient if you run multiple queries on the same input string. If you're only running one query per input, then it's slightly less efficient in terms of memory but not time, seeing as doing `GroupBy(...).Where(g => g.Count == n)` ends up counting all the groups anyway, and the main difference is that the lookup stores the results for all frequencies. Since the OP isn't clear about what they want it for, I thought it'd be a good idea to include this option. My bet is that they're building a frequency map.

Comment: Fair enough, certainly deserves upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string[] arrpattern = new string[textBox.Text.Length];
        int[] arrcount = new int[textBox.Text.Length];
        int counter=0;
        bool found;
        string pattern="";
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox.Text.Length-Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)+1; i++)
        {
            pattern=textBox.Text.Substring(i,Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
            if(counter==0)
            {
                arrpattern[0] = pattern;
                arrcount[0] = 1;
                counter++;

            }
            else
            {
                found = false;
                for(int j=0; j<counter;j++)
                {

                    if(arrpattern[j]==pattern)
                    {
                        arrcount[j] = arrcount[j] + 1;
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(found==false)
                {
                    arrpattern[counter] = pattern;
                    arrcount[counter] = 1;
                    counter++;
                }

            }
        }
        int max=0;
        for(int i =0; i<counter;i++)
        {
            if(arrcount[i]>max)
            {
                max = arrcount[i];
            }
        }
        textBox3.Text=max.ToString();
        textBox1.Text="";
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            if (arrcount[i] == max)
            {
                textBox1.Text += "," + arrpattern[i];
            }
        }
    }


}
```